# Reactjs, class component to hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still beginner with ReactJs. Actually I want to rewrite my class components to hook components but I have a problem with one part of my code. Anyone can help me with rewrite this component to hook?

This is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: {},
    data: data,
    filtered: data
  };

  handleChange = data => {
    if (data == null) {
      this.setState({
        filtered: this.state.data
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        selected: data,
        filtered: this.state.data.filter(d => d.client_id === data.id)
      });
    }
  };

  returnClientNameFromID = id => options.find(o => o.id === id).name;

  render() {
    const {
      state: { selected, data, filtered },
      handleChange
    } = this;


    return ( <div>
    ...
```

Comment: You seem to be running your current code on a magical computer that can assign a not previously declared value called `data` to state.data and state.filtered without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you could do. With `useState` you always have to merge objects yourself  `setState((prevState) => {...prevState, ... })`

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    selected: {},
    data: data,
    filtered: data
  })

  const handleChange = data => {
    if (data == null) {
      setState((prevState) => {
        ...prevState,
        filtered: this.state.data
      });
    } else {
      setState((prevState) => {
        ...prevState,
        selected: data,
        filtered: prevState.data.filter(d => d.client_id === data.id)
      });
    }
  };

  const returnClientNameFromID = id => options.find(o => o.id === id).name;

  const { selected, data, filtered } = state

  return() (
    <div> ... </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: No problem, I tried my best to keep it as simple as possible :) Could you accept the answer, if it works?